# Can I use a 24V 1A AC/DC adapter on a 9V 2A device? If so, are there negative effects of doing this?

Tags: voltage, amperage

I have a gaming chair with a speaker built into it and I lost the cord for it.  I managed to find an old xbox 360 cord that fit it but it’s 24V. The chair turns on with the 24V cord but I’m trying to find out if the higher voltage is hurting it.

Comment: do you really talking just about the cord, or do you mean a power supply?

Comment: Its a power supply i think

Comment: this is a power supply: http://images.esellerpro.com/2363/I/233/13/lrgscaleMicrosoft%20Xbox%20360%20UK%20AC%20Adapter%20%27Brick%27%20Power%20Supply.jpg
This is a cord: https://alexnld.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/SKU004625-1.jpg

Comment: it will blow up and stop working, it might catch on fire. The exciting thing is: Nobody knows when, maybe tomorrow maybe in 5 years.

Comment: I dont actually know if its a power supply. I would add a picture but its saying the image file is too large

Comment: Then crop and scale the image. 

Comment: Try harder to match the required voltage and current.  This could blow up caps.

Answer (score 1):

The negative effect will (probably) be damage to one of the circuits inside.

24V is nearly 3 times 9V so it is not a good idea.

Find a supply that matches.